# How to limit Visualforce lookup field to only lookup and show Users instead of other objects?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

So I have a VF page looking into a custom setting field - SetupOwner. The issue I'm having is I want to display only users and have end user only edit/add users to the custom settings as opposed to other objects (i.e. profile). See screenshot

[image]

Here is the page and extension I've been working with:

-------------- VF page -----------------------

```
        <apex:pageBlocktable value="{!UserQueueSettings}" var="ES" id="memberTable" rows="1000" >


            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:inputField value="{!ES.SetupOwnerId}"/>
            </apex:column>
```

-------------- Extension -----------------------

```
public List<UserQueueSettings__c> getUserQueueSettings()
{
    settings = [Select SetupOwnerId,Priority_1__c,Priority_2__c,Priority_3__c From UserQueueSettings__c where SetupOwner.Username != null];
    return settings;
}
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to use javascript / jquery to default all the dropdowns to the value User and then make them read only.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have created a Hierarchal custom setting.  This allows settings to be made at the org-wide, profile, and user levels; `SetupOwnerId` is the field that identifies what user/profile the record applies to.  By using `<apex:inputField>` with this field, VF is automatically generating the UI to select both profiles and users.

If you did intend to create a hierarchal custom setting but with to limit data entry to users only (no profiles), you probably want to avoid using `<apex:inputField>`.  Perhaps a two-step wizard interface, where a user first selects the new record user; you then insert a new custom setting record for that user and then display the UI, using `<apex:outputField>` for SetupOwnerId and `inputField`s for the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a dummy object that has a writeable lookup to `User`. For example if you had `My_Object__c` in your org with a `User__c` lookup, you could do something like:

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    public List<Wrapper> wrappers { get; private set; }
    public MyController()
    {
        // initialize wrappers, etc.
    }

    public PageReference save()
    {
        List<My_Setting__c> settings = new List<My_Setting__c>();
        for (Wrapper wrapper : wrappers) settings.add(wrapper.getSetting());
        update settings;
        // return whatever;
    }
    public class Wrapper
    {
        final My_Setting__c setting;
        public My_Object__c dummy { get; private set; }
        public Wrapper(My_Setting__c customSettingRecord)
        {
            setting = customSettingRecord;
            this.dummy = new My_Object__c(User__c=setting.SetupOwnerId);
        }
        My_Setting__c getSetting()
        {
            setting.SetupOwnerId = dummy.User__c;
            return setting;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use the wrapper lookup in your markup:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.dummy.User__c}" />
```